# I want to know if it's possible to give nth-child a class attritube

Tags: jquery, html, css, joomla, widget

Here's my problem. I'm working with a widget menu.

I want to add a different CSS rule to every li:nth-child with the ACTIVE class.
here's my code:

```
.wk-slideshow-default .nav .active
li:nth-child(1) span:hover {
width:19px;
height:18px;
background:url(/images/1r.png) !important;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Sound simple enough, right? Well, this code only works if I remove the li:nth-child(1). This is due to the fact that html works like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

I can't edit the HTML, due to this being a joomla extension.

Essentially, what I want to tell the CSS is:

```
if you are li:nth-child(1) without the active class, change background to 1.jpg
if you are li:nth-child(1) WITH the active class, change background to 1r.jpg
if you are li:nth-child(2) without the active class, change background to 2.jpg
if you are li:nth-child(2) WITH the active class, change background to 2r.jpg
```

so on and so forth. (without the active class already works fine)

Is there any way I could do it like... li:nth-child(1, .active)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `li.active:nth-child(1)`

By the hierarchy, you can set `element[attribute].class:pseudo`